# NSArray crashes my program when being used in a for loop

Tags: objective-c, arrays, multidimensional-array, nsmutablearray, nsarray

I am using SQLite3 to grab data from a Database. So I am trying to make an Multidimensional array to hold an array of all records which is a nested array within an array. So when the loop gets to this code:

```
[[studentsInfo objectAtIndex:recordRow] addObject: [NSMutableArray arrayWithObjects:studentLastName, studentFirstName, studentID, studentEmail, programName, majorityCampus, discipline, cmName, cmID, cmEmail, cmPhone, cmCampus, studentNotes, nil]];
```

it crashes. Here is what I get from Xcode.

[image: Snapshot]

Here is the full code what am I doing wrong?

```
    - (void) initializeDatabase {

    // get the documents directory
    NSArray *dirPaths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
    NSString *docsDir = dirPaths[0];
    NSLog(@"Directory Path: %@", docsDir);

    FindYourMentorDB_Path = [[NSString alloc]initWithString:[docsDir stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"FindYourCM_Info.sqlite"]];

    NSFileManager *fileManager = [NSFileManager defaultManager];

    if ([fileManager fileExistsAtPath:FindYourMentorDB_Path] == NO) {

        // attempt to open the db
        if (sqlite3_open([FindYourMentorDB_Path UTF8String], &_FindYourMentorDB) == SQLITE_OK){

            sqlite3_close(_FindYourMentorDB); // Close the DB

            NSLog(@"Succeeded in opening FindYourMentorDB");
        } else {

            NSLog(@"Failed to Open the FindYourMentorDB");
        } // END OF IF

    } // END OF IF

    NSMutableArray *studentsInfo = [NSMutableArray new];

    sqlite3_stmt *statement;

    if (sqlite3_open([FindYourMentorDB_Path UTF8String], &_FindYourMentorDB) == SQLITE_OK) {

        NSString *selectSQL = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"SELECT StudentLastName, StudentFirstName, StudentID, StudentEmail, ProgramName, MajorityCampus, Discipline, CMName, CMID, CMEmail, CMPhone, CMCampus, StudentNotes FROM FindYourCM_DB"];

        const char *selectStmt = [selectSQL UTF8String];

        if (sqlite3_prepare_v2(_FindYourMentorDB, selectStmt, -1, &statement, NULL) == SQLITE_OK) {

            for (int recordRow = 0; sqlite3_step(statement) == SQLITE_ROW; recordRow++) {

                NSString *studentLastName = [[NSString alloc]initWithUTF8String:(const char*)sqlite3_column_text(statement,0)];

                NSString *studentFirstName = [[NSString alloc]initWithUTF8String:(const char*)sqlite3_column_text(statement, 1)];

                NSString *studentID = [[NSString alloc]initWithUTF8String:(const char*)sqlite3_column_text(statement, 2)];

                NSString *studentEmail = [[NSString alloc]initWithUTF8String:(const char*)sqlite3_column_text(statement, 3)];

                NSString *programName = [[NSString alloc]initWithUTF8String:(const char*)sqlite3_column_text(statement, 4)];

                NSString *majorityCampus = [[NSString alloc]initWithUTF8String:(const char*)sqlite3_column_text(statement, 5)];

                NSString *discipline = [[NSString alloc]initWithUTF8String:(const char*)sqlite3_column_text(statement, 6)];

                NSString *cmName = [[NSString alloc]initWithUTF8String:(const char*)sqlite3_column_text(statement, 7)];

                NSString *cmID = [[NSString alloc]initWithUTF8String:(const char*)sqlite3_column_text(statement, 8)];

                NSString *cmEmail = [[NSString alloc]initWithUTF8String:(const char*)sqlite3_column_text(statement, 9)];

                NSString *cmPhone = [[NSString alloc]initWithUTF8String:(const char*)sqlite3_column_text(statement, 10)];

                NSString *cmCampus = [[NSString alloc]initWithUTF8String:(const char*)sqlite3_column_text(statement, 11)];

                NSString *studentNotes = [[NSString alloc]initWithUTF8String:(const char*)sqlite3_column_text(statement, 12)];

                [[studentsInfo objectAtIndex:recordRow] addObject: [NSMutableArray arrayWithObjects:studentLastName, studentFirstName, studentID, studentEmail, programName, majorityCampus, discipline, cmName, cmID, cmEmail, cmPhone, cmCampus, studentNotes, nil]];
            }

            sqlite3_finalize(statement);
        }

        sqlite3_close(_FindYourMentorDB);
    }
}
```

Comment: You probably want to remove the `objectAtIndex:` part of `[studentsInfo objectAtIndex:recordRow]`.

Comment: may be there is no array at index recordRow. so first you have to add array at recordRow index.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out. The StudentNotes in the DB was NULL so that was causing it to crash. So I changed the code to this. Thanks for all the help.

[image]

Comment: No, the error in your question has nothing to do with `studentNotes` being `NULL`. You need to fix the code as shown in my answer.

Answer (score 0):

The primary problem is this line:

```
[[studentsInfo objectAtIndex:recordRow] addObject: [NSMutableArray arrayWithObjects:studentLastName, studentFirstName, ...
```

Since `studentsInfo` is a new, empty array, there is nothing to access from it. You simply want to add to it as follows:

```
[studentsInfo addObject: [NSMutableArray arrayWithObjects:studentLastName, studentFirstName, ...
```

There are a few other things you can clean up as well.

```
- (void) initializeDatabase {
    // get the documents directory
    NSArray *dirPaths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
    NSString *docsDir = dirPaths[0];
    NSLog(@"Directory Path: %@", docsDir);

    findYourMentorDB_Path = [docsDir stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"FindYourCM_Info.sqlite"];

    NSMutableArray *studentsInfo = [NSMutableArray new];

    if (sqlite3_open([findYourMentorDB_Path UTF8String], &_findYourMentorDB) == SQLITE_OK) {
        NSString *selectSQL = @"SELECT StudentLastName, StudentFirstName, StudentID, StudentEmail, ProgramName, MajorityCampus, Discipline, CMName, CMID, CMEmail, CMPhone, CMCampus, StudentNotes FROM FindYourCM_DB";

        const char *selectStmt = [selectSQL UTF8String];

        sqlite3_stmt *statement;
        if (sqlite3_prepare_v2(_findYourMentorDB, selectStmt, -1, &statement, NULL) == SQLITE_OK) {
            while (sqlite3_step(statement) == SQLITE_ROW) {
                NSString *studentLastName = [[NSString alloc]initWithUTF8String:(const char*)sqlite3_column_text(statement,0)];
                NSString *studentFirstName = [[NSString alloc]initWithUTF8String:(const char*)sqlite3_column_text(statement, 1)];
                NSString *studentID = [[NSString alloc]initWithUTF8String:(const char*)sqlite3_column_text(statement, 2)];
                NSString *studentEmail = [[NSString alloc]initWithUTF8String:(const char*)sqlite3_column_text(statement, 3)];
                NSString *programName = [[NSString alloc]initWithUTF8String:(const char*)sqlite3_column_text(statement, 4)];
                NSString *majorityCampus = [[NSString alloc]initWithUTF8String:(const char*)sqlite3_column_text(statement, 5)];
                NSString *discipline = [[NSString alloc]initWithUTF8String:(const char*)sqlite3_column_text(statement, 6)];
                NSString *cmName = [[NSString alloc]initWithUTF8String:(const char*)sqlite3_column_text(statement, 7)];
                NSString *cmID = [[NSString alloc]initWithUTF8String:(const char*)sqlite3_column_text(statement, 8)];
                NSString *cmEmail = [[NSString alloc]initWithUTF8String:(const char*)sqlite3_column_text(statement, 9)];
                NSString *cmPhone = [[NSString alloc]initWithUTF8String:(const char*)sqlite3_column_text(statement, 10)];
                NSString *cmCampus = [[NSString alloc]initWithUTF8String:(const char*)sqlite3_column_text(statement, 11)];
                NSString *studentNotes = [[NSString alloc]initWithUTF8String:(const char*)sqlite3_column_text(statement, 12)];

                [studentsInfo addObject:@[ studentLastName, studentFirstName, studentID, studentEmail, programName, majorityCampus, discipline, cmName, cmID, cmEmail, cmPhone, cmCampus, studentNotes ]];
            }

            sqlite3_finalize(statement);
        } else {
            NSLog(@"Unable to prepare statement: %s", sqlite3_errmsg(_findYourMentorDB));
        }

        sqlite3_close(_findYourMentorDB);
    } else {
        NSLog(@"Unable to open database at %@", findYourMentorDB_Path);
    }
}
```

Issues:

1. What do you do with the `studentsInfo` array once it is populated?
2. Use proper naming conventions - variable and method names should start with lowercase letters. Class names begin with uppercase letters.
3. Log errors so you know why things don't work.
4. Your check for the database file followed by a needless and open and close aren't needed. If the database file doesn't exist, it will be created by default when using `sqlite3_open`.

Comment: Thank you. You solved another issue I was having as well!

Comment: Glad I could help. If the answer solved your issue, you should accept the answer to indicate that your question is solved.

Answer (score -1):

Used next method: `insertObject:yourarray atIndex:yourindex`